# How to work with an object that was instantiated inside another object from a ASP.NET web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

This is probably a very simple question but I'm a little confused when it comes to working with an object created from a class that contains a field where the type is another class. The part that confuses me is how to populate the field with data from the web form.

For example, if I have a `customer` class that has a field called `contact` which is of type `Contact`, what is the proper way to populate this at the web form level?  At present I am doing it as follows and would like to know if this is correct.

This is the code from my `customer` class and `contact` is another class.

```
public class Customer
{
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName'
    private string notes;
    private Contact contact;

    public Customer()
    {
        this.contact = new Contact();
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }
    public string Notes
    {
        get { return notes; }
        set { notes = value; }
    }
    public Contact Contact
    {
        get { return contact; }
        set { contact = value; }
    }
}
```

Code from my form

```
private Customer customer;

public WebFormSample()
{
     customer = new AddressBook.Customer();
}
protected void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     customer.FirstName = firstName.Text;
     customer.LastName = lastName.Text;
     customer.Contact.Phone = phone.Text;
     customer.Contact.Email = Email.Text;
}
```

Is this the way I should be working with the `contact` object or should I have instantiated a `contact` object on the web form, populate it and then assign it to contact in the `customer` object or have I got it completely wrong and this should be done in a completely different way?

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the code you posted? Because I would expect `customer.Contact` to be `null` as you never created an instance for it.

So you can fix your existing code like this:

```
customer.Contact = new Contact();
customer.Contact.Phone = phone.Text;
customer.Contact.Email = Email.Text;
```

Or you can do as you were asking about:

```
var contact = new Contact();
contact.Phone = phone.Text;
contact.Email = Email.Text;
customer.Contact = contact;
```

Depending on your needs, either should work.

Comment: You're right about Customer.Contact being null, the reason I initialized it in the Customer class was because I was going create a new contact in the web form and assign it to Cusomter.Contact using a property.  At this point I think there is something flawd in my design of this class along with all the related classes because when I pass Customer to the method that saves it to the database, I find that I'm chaining togeather a long list of properties and I'm wonder if that's a bad coding practice.  eg. Customer.Contact.Address.Email.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:-

```
Customer.Contact = new Contact { Phone = phone.Text
                                          , Email = Email.text };
```

Answer (score 0):

Customer class should not have the responsible of creating Contact class, it should take Contact instances from outside(via constructor or public property).

If have a chance, you should read more about Dependency Injection.